# React HMR with SSR

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to setup SSR for React-application, when I am starting server at the first time in `development` environment all works good (server sending browser HTML and CSS), after changing source code of my application I getting an error:

[image]

This error was throwing because on server source code is outdated, but client has a new version and React notify me over this trouble. I think the solve of this trouble is mechanism called HMR (hot module replacement), but setting up this is hard for me.

My server Webpack-config looks like this:

```
const serverConfig = merge(commonConfig, {
  name: 'server',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
      whitelist: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000'],
    }),
  ],
  entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000', appServerEntry],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(appDist, 'server'),
    filename: 'index.js',
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
});
```

On each request server render a new version of UI

```
app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  const staticAssets = getStaticAssets();
  const routerContext = {};
  const renderStream = renderDocumentToStream({
    staticAssets,
    request,
    routerContext,
  });
  const cacheStream = createCacheStream(request.path);

  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  response.write('<!DOCTYPE html>');

  cacheStream.pipe(response);
  renderStream.pipe(cacheStream);
});
```

For the hot reload I use `webpackDevMiddleware` and `webpackHotMiddleware`

```
const webpackInstance = webpack(webpackConfig);
const clientCompiler = webpackInstance.compilers.find(cmpl => cmpl.name === 'client');

app.use(
  webpackDevMiddleware(clientCompiler, {
    hot: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
  }),
);
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(clientCompiler));
```

`renderDocumentToStream` function intended for render `App` to `NodeStream`:

```
import App from './App';

renderDocumentToStream: ({ request, staticAssets, routerContext }) => {
  const rootMarkup = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={request.url} context={routerContext}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  return renderToNodeStream(
    <Document
      rootMarkup={rootMarkup}
      staticAssets={staticAssets}
    />,
  );
},

if (module.hot) {
  console.log('HERE-0');
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    console.log('HERE-1');
  });
}
```

When server is starting in `stdout` logged first call of `console.log`

[image]

second call of `console.log` not logged, even after `App.jsx` has been changed

[image]

What a im doing wrong?

Comment: That is not the problem, can you start by posting the code where you have `Home`

Comment: This is probably happening because the HTML that is rendered in the server doesn't match the HTML that the client wants to render.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is clearly indicating that the content is different at client from server. This is not an error but a warning which means, there are going to be performance impact because React has to re-render at client and so the whole purpose of having SSR will be defeated.
Please check and make sure that client is also getting the same for hydration as the server. This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to solve because the server side will not refresh on change with HMR.

Personally when doing React with SSR I setup `nodemon` to listen to file changes on the SSR output files and restart the application. Unfortunately this isn't as fast as HMR and you lose current state, but I do not think there is an alternative if you will be using SSR (or ignore the warnings)

This is also the case when using Next.js: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/791

Answer (score 0):

This warning could mean you have a component that needs to render differently on the client side, and you are not making sure your "first-pass" render is the same on the server and the client side.

It is okay for them to differ, for instance, if you load a spinner when there is no data, and this data is not going to be there on the server side, then go ahead and guarantee the spinner always renders on the server and on the "first-pass" render on the browser (the render call before componentDidMount() is fired) are identical.

Then when your data is there trigger a state change to "2nd-pass" render.

Also, one thing I warn against is using the `module.hot ? ReactDOM.render : ReactDOM.hydrate`.

I regretted using this method at work, because it masks hard to detect mismatches in development.